# Debug log in Scala with no performance impact

Tags: debugging, scala, optimization, logging, preprocessor

In languages like C/C++/Objective-C it's common to use preprocessor macros to define logging mechanisms that are not even compiled for released binaries, thus causing no performance hit. Something along the lines of:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
printf("some event we want to log\n");
#endif
```

Now, I know there's no preprocessor in Scala. So my question is: what is the best way to implement a mechanism to log program activity for debug purposes, while impacting performance the least when it's turned off?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`scala.annotation.elidable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/elidable.html)

> An annotation for methods for which invocations might be removed in the generated code.
>
> Behavior is influenced by passing -Xelide-below  to scalac. Methods marked elidable will be omitted from generated code if the priority given the annotation is lower than to the command line argument. Examples:

Comment: It's a good idea but not perfect: it's a close match to the C/C++ approach. But you now have to manage multiple versions of compiled binaries instead of one.

Answer (score 5):

Current practice (in Scala 2.9.x or earlier) is to use a thunk type (e.g. see Simple Logging Facade for Scala [SLFS](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s)):

```
def log(x: =>Any) = if (logging) println(x)

// later in code
log("var1: " + myVar1)
```

This is often less expensive than actually constructing the string, since the string creation (and any subsequent activity) is only done if `logging` is true. However, it still incurs the cost of closure creation for the thunk `x` above.

However, starting from Scala 2.10.x, there is an experimental macro implementation included in the standard distribution (see [this page](http://scalamacros.org/), or [SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/self-cleaning-macros.html)). The macro system will allow you to write logging calls which incur almost no runtime cost (other than the `logging` variable check) - they allow you to inline the call to `log`, so that this:

```
log("var1: " + myVar1)
```

becomes:

```
if (logging) log("var1: " + myVar1)
```

Notice that in this case there is no closure created for `log`, and the logging message string is only evaluated if `logging` is true - the cost is only the if-check.

Comment: Macros can also introspect compiler settings and emit an empty tree if these settings tell to omit the logs altogether.

Comment: True - if you know during compile-time that no logging is required, then there are no runtime costs at all.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the sort of simple solution I was looking for! I'm aware of the experimental macro implementation on 2.10.x and looking forward to playing with it, but I'm still in 2.9 land for now.

Comment: You may want to take a look at `@elidable` that @senia mentions.

Answer (score 1):

[Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) is a common JVM logging framework.  It is specifically designed to have minimal performance impact:

> On an AMD Duron clocked at 800Mhz running JDK 1.3.1, it costs about 5 nanoseconds to determine if a logging statement should be logged or not. Actual logging is also quite fast, ranging from 21 microseconds using the SimpleLayout, 37 microseconds using the TTCCLayout. The performance of the PatternLayout is almost as good as the dedicated layouts, except that it is much more flexible.

So when you make a call like:

```
LOG.debug("something here")
```

the framework will first check if "debug" logging is enabled.  This check is very fast.  If logging is disabled, then it doesn't do any more work.

There is one catch however.  If you write

```
LOG.debug(expensiveOperation())
```

then the framework won't do the debug-enabled check before performing the expensive operation.  The way to correct for this is to say:

```
if(LOG.isDebugEnabled) LOG.debug(expensiveOperation())
```

Comment: Log4J is seriously outdated. Building a string can be costly, specially if you concatenate several values together. SLF4J (or SLFS) for instance uses a simple strategy to build the string only when needed.

Comment: @paradigmatic: Looking at the code, SLF4S is doing the same thing (`if (slf4jLogger.isDebugEnabled) slf4jLogger.debug(msg, t)`), but *also* wrapping the message in a closure.  So it saves you nothing and adds on the cost of creating a closure.  The closure version is certainly cleaner, but I don't think you can claim it's faster.

Comment: This should be compared to the cost of building a string such as: `"Request: " + request + "; context: " + ctx + "; version: " + v`. Using a call-by-name or the strategy used in slf4j cancels that cost.

Comment: @paradigmatic is right, SLF4J allows to pass message placeholders in a vararg and thus the "real" string is not build unless logging is enabled